# Enviar dados para outra tab através do "ion-option-button"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Como posso enviar os dados de uma tab para outra tab ao clicar no componente "ion-option-button"?
Essa tab destino terá um formulário, a intenção é editar os dados contidos em um "".
Dados para exibição consegui fazer através do:

```
`<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">`
```

Comment: você pode fazer isso por get, passando os dados no parâmetro da url, e recuperando o conteúdo, ou então via manipulado cookies, mas qual teria de se montar uma rotina pra gravar e recuperar este cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já fiz isso antes passando parâmetros nas URLs, mas a experiência me mostrou que é melhor montar uma factory e gravar os dados lá. Fica mais organizado e centralizado. Mas também depende da natureza dos seus dados e tal.